# RxJava Thread.sleep() interrupted exception

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm working on something with RxJava (custom caching observable) and I found following problem.

Example is straightforward simple: Creates observable, subscribers and immediately unsubscribes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Observable<Long> origin = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Long>() {
    @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Long> subscriber) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting... > " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            subscriber.onNext(System.currentTimeMillis());
            Thread.sleep(200);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
            System.out.println("Complete...");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
    }
});

Subscription sub1 = origin.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {
    @Override public void onCompleted() { }
    @Override public void onError(Throwable e) { e.printStackTrace();  }
    @Override public void onNext(Long value) {
        System.out.println("onNext() > " + value);
    }
});

try {
    sub1.unsubscribe();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    System.in.read(); // wait for user input to finish
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

If you run following program several times you should get following exception (try until you get exception)

```
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.skendel.Program$1.call(Program.java:23)
    at org.skendel.Program$1.call(Program.java:19)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7710)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:62)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.skendel.Program$1.call(Program.java:23)
    at org.skendel.Program$1.call(Program.java:19)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7710)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:62)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**My question is: why is this exception (sometimes) happening?** 
It happens even .cache() observable is created.

Exception is tied to the first Thread.sleep() call in the implementation of Observable.OnSubscribe()

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to unsubscribe an event which is currently running (`Thread.sleep()`). Your library apparently detects this and tries to wake your event to stop it. You should not rely on `Sleep()` in your code, anyway. There is always a better, more proper way. Plus, as a thumb of the rule, an event should always be as fast as possible.

The Exception won't occur if you unsubscribe fast enough: your event didn't fire, it's not sleeping, so there's no exception.

Try to delay the unsubscribe a second, and it should fire all the time, and create an Exception all the time too.

Answer (score 1):

Spinning up a new thread may take some time (even 1ms) which gives the main thread plenty of time to unsubscribe thus cancel the task scheduled by `subscribeOn`. Other times, the thread spins up so fast that it starts running the `OnSubscribe` code which is now interrupted by the unsubscribe call.

As others mentioned, you should try to avoid sleeps in your code but instead, setup the sequence with `delay`s or simply use a `Scheduler.Worker.schedule()` to trigger actions after some time.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption would be the exception is NOT happening only if main thread reaches the `sub1.unsubscribe();` line before Observable goes to sleep, because it is the `unsubscribe` call that wakes the Observable the hard way - as it deletes the thread `origin` is subscribed to.

This exception seems expected, so handle it separately, not in onError() method.